# Are ActiveRecord:Observer callbacks called during unit testing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, testing

I'm trying to unit test an observer in rails but none of its callbacks are being invoked. I'm sure I have something configured incorrectly but just to be sure I was wondering if this may be a Rails limitation during unit testing.

I've looked at the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Observer.html) and they don't mention anything.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Callbacks defined in observers work perfectly in unit testing. It must be something wrong with your config files. Why don't you post your `config/environment.rb` file so we can check?

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

If you add your observers to `config/environment.rb`, these observers will be run in development, test or whatever environment.

If you add your observers to `config/environments/development.rb`, they will be used in this specific environment only.